# SparkSQL Dataframe Error: value show is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I'm new to Spark/Scala/Dataframes.  I'm using Scala 2.10.5, Spark 1.6.0.  I am trying to load in a csv file and then create a dataframe from it.  Using the scala shell I execute the following in the order below. Once I execute line 6, I get an error that says:

`error: value show is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader`

Could someone advise what I might be missing? I understand I don't need to import sparkcontext if I'm using the REPL (shell) so sc will be automatically created, but any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

1.`import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext`

2. `import sqlContext.implicits._`
3. `val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)`
4. `val csvfile = "path_to_filename in hdfs...."`
5. `val df = sqlContext.read.format(csvfile).option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true")`
6. `df.show()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
val df = sqlContext.read.option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").csv(csvfile)
```

`sqlContext.read` gives you a `DataFrameReader`, and `option` and `format` both set some options and give you back a `DataFrameReader`. You need to call one of the methods that gives you a `DataFrame` (like `csv`) before you can do things like `show` with it.

See https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader for more info.

Comment: Thank you!! I'm going to try that now

Comment: ..I just tried your suggestion and it's giving me the error: value csv is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.  Do you think it's b/c I'm not importing something I should?

Comment: Ah, looks like that method was added relatively recently. Sorry, don't have a 1.6.0 installation handy to test... maybe try `.format("csv").load(csvFile)` instead?

Comment: omg thank you thank you! I even tried spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.5.0 but that didn't work, but your suggestion did. I'm working on a project that's due tomorrow so I hope you wouldn't mind me reaching out again with more questions (if any)!

Comment: Actually, to clarify, I also needed to add spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.5.0 and then use your suggestion in order for it to work.  Thanks again!